# On Error Resume Next in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, exception

Does `try ... catch(e)` provide the same service as `On Error Resume Next` in VB?

I have a page which uses several JQuery plugins as well as some functions I have written myself. It would take a lot of work to address all possible exceptions.

For now, I want to tell the script not to break on would be fatal errors. How do I do that when I'm using plugins?

Comment: An exception is exceptional, how can you continue to run the script if everything is messed up? :)

Comment: Not `everything` is messed up. Rather, only something around 10% ;)

Comment: @user216441, After you've sorted the mess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `try`/`catch` provides a way to capture errors, though unlike On Error Resume Next you choose to deal with the error in the `catch` block or not at all.

So in VB you might have done:

```
on error resume next
DoSomethingUnsavory
if err.number <> 0 then ...
on error goto 0 ' you DO do this, right?
```

In JS you'd do the following:

```
try {
    doSomethingUnsavory();
}
catch (e) {
    // handle the unsavoriness if needed
}
```

Of course empty catch blocks are evil so don't leave them in production code yadda yadda.  The best thing is to let the errors occur and fix them. Fail fast!

Comment: Thank you. The error I'm dealing with is caused by validation plugin on nested forms. I'm aware of it and trying to fix. But other functions are crippled because of this (only on some browsers). I want a quick scotch-tape fix for now, until I find a way to prevent the error from occurring.

Comment: This is NOT correct, I know this thread is very old but this information is misleading, on error resume next ignores errors and continues on the next sentence, try/catch exits from the try body and enters on catch when an error is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

According to my knowledge there is no ON ERROR RESUME NEXT in javascript, but the following model will solve your requirement

```
try
{
    var providerRateAvg = data.entry.gd$rating.average;
}
catch(e)
{}
```